# A quantity associated with an algebraic variete

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, matrices

Let $P:\mathbb{C}^{n}\to \mathbb{C}$ be  an irreducible homogenous polynomial.

Is there a  geometric or algebra geometric interpretation for the following quantity:

The maximum number $k$ such that there is  a  $k$  dimensional subvector  space $Y$ of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$  which is  included in $P=0$?

Moreover,  what is this  quantity for $Det:M_{n}(\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathbb{C}^{n^{2}}\to \mathbb{C}$?

This  question is motivated by the following post:

[Finite codimensional subvector space of $C^{*}$ algebras which contains no invertible elements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195950/finite-codimensional-subvector-space-of-c-algebras-which-contains-no-inver?noredirect=1#comment488733_195950)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "interpretation". The definition seems geometric enough to me.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Is there any known name for this quantity and what are some properties for this? By geometric I mean: it seems that if this quantity would be large, the variete can not be so "cuvrved". So assuming the real version of this question, the first part of my question is about a possible relation between this quantity and for example some upper bound for the  absolute value of the sectional curvature at regular points. Or may be some other interpretation... Now is it clear what I mean?

Comment: Perhaps your question is related to this question:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15106/can-projective-hypersurfaces-contain-linear-spaces-how-big

Comment: @MahdiMajidi-Zolbanin  Thank you very much for the interesting link.